# Kettle Exception: Formula step is invalid as a target

Tags: kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a formula step [invert sum] in kettle transformation but when I run the transformation on server, it returns me the error: Step[invert sum] is invalid as a target.
I’ve excluded the possibility that the divisor is zero. And the previous steps are two filtering steps plus one group by step.
The order is : filter 1 -yes- filter2
Filter 1 -no- group by
Filter 2 -yes- group by
Group by - formula

I have no idea why this error happens since when I used dummy data to test, there was no error.
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Does the Filter 2 has a step for -no- ? If don't, try that with a Dummy step.